# Plot to show the expression of genes between tumor and normal

Tags: r, rna-seq, rna, visualization, ggplot2

I have RNA-seq raw counts data for 50 samples. 20 Normal and 30 tumor. After differential analysis I got 30 DEGs. I want to make a violin plot showing the expression of each gene. I transformed counts to logCPM.

counts:

```
Genes   Tumor1  Tumor2  Normal1 Normal2
RP11-351J23.1   0   5   6   0
MIR17HG 989 896 8   0
RP11-563N12.2   0   0   0   0
LINC04393   0   2   16  0
RP11-336A10.4   0   0   0   0
DRH6-AB1    53  13  39  9
RP11-115J16.1   0   0   50  6
LINC70518   2   65  0   0

logCPM <- cpm(counts, prior.count=2, log = TRUE)

                Tumor1   Tumor2  Normal1  Normal2
RP11-351J23.1 11.84477 13.09301 15.71337 11.84477
MIR17HG      19.84847 19.79600 16.10350 11.84477
RP11-563N12.2 11.84477 11.84477 11.84477 11.84477
LINC04393     11.84477 12.47723 17.06532 11.84477
RP11-336A10.4 11.84477 11.84477 11.84477 11.84477
DRH6-AB1      15.72257 14.03896 18.32772 19.19283
RP11-115J16.1 11.84477 11.84477 18.68262 18.61229
LINC70518     12.44599 16.08368 11.84477 11.84477
```

I want to make violin plot for each gene showing expression for Tumors and Normals with this.

I first transformed logCPM. then tried like below:

```
ggplot2.violinplot(data=logCPM, xName='RP11-351J23.1',
    groupName='Tumor', position=position_dodge(0.8), 
    backgroundColor="white", groupColors=c('#999999','#E69F00'),
    legendPosition="top")
```

Comment: From what package is this `ggplot2.violinplot` function? Could you upload the image you get and why it doesn't meet your requirements?

Comment: "easyGgplot2" is the package. I didn't get any plot. something went wrong and no error also.

Comment: Could you post your `sessionInfo` then? And is there any reason why you use this function and not the base ggplot2 functions?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use long-form data for everything:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
logCPM$gene = row.names(logCPM)
d = logCPM %>% gather(Sample, logCPM, -gene)
d$group = c(rep("Tumor", 2), rep("Normal", 2))
geneOfInterest = d %>% filter(gene == 'RP11-351J23.1')
ggplot(geneOfInterest, aes(x=group, y=logCPM)) + geom_violin()
```

That's a simple example, you can tweak it to meet your needs.

Comment: With logCPM mentioned in my question I have used your code. But there're some warnings and error. `logCPM$gene = row.names(logCPM)
Warning message:
In logCPM$gene = row.names(logCPM) : Coercing LHS to a list; d = logCPM %>% gather(Sample, logCPM, -gene)
Error in UseMethod("gather_") : 
  no applicable method for 'gather_' applied to an object of class "list"`

Comment: Make sure `logCPM` is a data.frame

Comment: yes. but In the plot I can see only Tumor. There is no Normal. https://imgur.com/a/LnxG4DN And how to add asterisks to denote a significant difference?

Comment: You somehow filtered out the normal samples. You can figure out how that happened. You can add characters with `geom_text()`, please see the ggplot documentation.

Comment: I followed the code. But dataframe "d" looks like this;                                                gene  Sample   logCPM  group
1  RP11-351J23.1  Tumor1 11.84477  Tumor
2       MIR137HG  Tumor1 19.84847  Tumor
3  RP11-563N12.2  Tumor1 11.84477 Normal
4      LINC00393  Tumor1 11.84477 Normal
5  RP11-336A10.4  Tumor1 11.84477  Tumor
6       DLX6-AS1  Tumor1 15.72257  Tumor
7  RP11-115J16.1  Tumor1 11.84477 Normal
8      LINC00518  Tumor1 12.44599 Normal

Comment: Ah, you'll need to change the d$gene assignment line.